# jQuery Slide Toggle help

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("a.sticky-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("div.stickies-box").slideToggle('slow');
        $("a.sticky-link").toggleClass("selected");
    });

    $("div.stickies-box").mouseup(function () {
        return false
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).parent("a.sticky-link").length == 0) {
            $("a.sticky-link").removeClass("selected");
            $("div.stickies-box").slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
```

Which basically shows and hides a div when a user clicks a button and then hides it should they click anywhere else on the page. The problem I have is if the box is already shown and the user clicks the button again (assuming they intend to hide the box) it will just quickly hide and reshow the box, when all I want it to do is hide the box.

Also instead of sliding can the effect be changed to actually moving up and down as the slide effect looks more like a wipe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your mouseup event will fire before the click event on the `<a>`.

You can detect that your mouseup event isn't occuring on the `a.sticky-link` or the `div.stickies-box` before hiding the box:

```
$("a.sticky-link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("div.stickies-box").slideToggle('slow');
    $("a.sticky-link").toggleClass("selected");
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var $targ = $(e.target);
    // if we are the link or the box, exit early
    if ($targ.is('a.sticky-link') || $targ.is('div.stickies-box')) return; 
    // if we have a parent who is either, also exit early
    if ($targ.closest('a.sticky-link,div.stickies-box').length) return;

    // hide the box, unselect the link
    $("a.sticky-link").removeClass("selected");
    $("div.stickies-box").slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: Bit more code than I would of liked but it works great thanks. Any ideas about the alternate effect so that the box moves upwards rather than the wipe effect?

Comment: Assuming an absolute positioned box, you could use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) to change its "top" to push it off the screen if that's what you mean.

Comment: Just noticed a problem. I have to click the button to close the box, I also want it to hide if a user clicks anywhere else on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I was just thinking about it, and will be deleting my other answer if this one ends up working...

You might be able to just [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the mouseup events, replace the one you currently have for `div.stickies-box` with this:

```
$("div.stickies-box,a.sticky-link").mouseup(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Turns out your original code works fine but on some pages isn't working, not sure why yet. But if you think you have a better solution, please feel free to update your answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

see-

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/